# How to correctly navigate with navigation's stack in Xamarin.ios?

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm currently working on a project in Xamarin.iOS and I don't have any idea how the stack system works.

I have a menu where I choose the language of my app and I would like to refresh on the fly the language on all the previous pages when I select a different language.

When I tap on the previous button in my language settings the previous page is not translated so I decided to create a new `ViewController` that I put on the top of the stack with `this.NavigationController.PushViewController(new ViewController(), true)`

but I don't think it's the best way to do it so I tried

`this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true)` to have the root `ViewController` but is there a way to get just the previous page on the stack?

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = this.GetCell(tableView, indexPath);

    cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

    var previousIndexPath = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(this.selectedIndex, 0);

    this.selectedIndex = indexPath.Row;

    var selectedLanguage = this.supportedCultures[this.selectedIndex];

    Localization.Culture = selectedLanguage;

    this.SaveLanguageToUserDefault(selectedLanguage);

    this.TableView.ReloadRows(new NSIndexPath[] { previousIndexPath,indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);


    this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true); 

    //this.NavigationController.PushViewController(new ViewController(), true);

}
```

Comment: Do you want to reload previous `ViewController` on back pressed?

Comment: Yes, reload previous ViewController when I push Previous and refresh him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS if you are using a **NavigationController** and you want to Navigate to the previous ViewController you use the **PopViewController** Method in the NavigationProperty.

`this.NavigationController.PopViewController(true);`

This will make you app close the current page you are and will show the previous one.

Look that this is different to the `PopToRootViewController`.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's better to use PopViewController instead of PopToRootViewController in my case

Answer (score 0):

When you press back button `ViewDidAppear` medthod getting called in the coming page. Here you write your logic like *after opening notification when going back setting count `0` etc*

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated) 
{
  base.ViewDidAppear(animated);                      
  DashboardItem.NotificationCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: I found how the previous system works but the refresh is still a problem

Comment: @Heisenbelge - Who knows what you want to refresh and how. Still if there is something people can help you then please ask new question.